# How to use drawer layout and navigation View?

Tags: android, android-layout

i created a **drawer layout** it showing in design but app doesn't open .
also i included a other layout behind of drawer but i doesn't creeated actionbar . plz help me to find out the problem .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        tools:openDrawer="start"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/standard_calculator"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"></include>
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/back_secondary_button"
            >


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_48sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"

                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/menu_icon_foreground"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>



    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

plz help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please share your Java or Kotlin code so I can check the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was issue in your xml design and I checked the code you are using drawerlayout with wrap_content instead of match_parent which is causing the crash. I modified your code which is running properly without any error. Below is your modified code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
    layout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></include>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```